# Probability of drawing 3 certain cards?

Tags: probability, card-games

Say I have 10 cards uniformly distributed with probability 1/10. You now draw without replacement. Then I can use the binomial coefficient to compute the probability of drawing 3 cards where 1 certain card is not included:
$$
\frac{\text{#ways to choose 3 cards from 9 cards}}{\text{#ways to choose 3 cards from 10 cards}}
$$
This gives 0.7. Thus, it just gave the same result as my intuition told me. What it said was: The probability of drawing certain 3 cards is 30% so 1-30%=70%=0.7 which is the probability of not drawing this 3-card-combo which means you didn't draw that 1 card. However, why is my intuition matching the use of the binomial coefficient? Is the probability of drawing 3 cards really 30%? I mean I would say there is $\frac{1}{10*9*8}$ chance of drawing a certain 3-card-combo :/

Comment: I don't understand your intuitive argument at all.  The probability of drawing a specific $3$ card hand is $\frac 1{\binom {10}3}=.008\overline 3$.

Comment: @lulu I don't really either... so why does it give me the right result :/

Comment: As far as I can see, you just wrote down a string of random numbers that happened to come to $.7$   I don't see any argument there at all.

Comment: Try a different one:  In a $38$ card deck from which you draw a $7$ card hand, what is the probability you do not draw the $38$?  What does your intuition say here?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't that the probability of drawing $3$ cards is $30\%$.  Suppose that the card to be excluded is the Ace of Spades.  Then what your original question amounts to is:

Suppose that you divide up $10$ cards into $2$ groups, where one of the groups has $3$ cards and one of the groups has $7$ cards.  What is the probability that the Ace of Spades is in the $7$ card group?

Answer:
The Ace of Spades has a $(1/10)$th probability of being any one of the $10$ cards.  These **disjoint** probabilities are **additive**. So, the probability that the Ace of Spades is in the group of $3$ cards is $30\%$.  Therefore, the probability that the Ace of Spades is not in the group of $3$ cards is $[100\% - 30\% = 70\%].$

The reason that this computation matches the result of the $~\displaystyle \frac{\binom{9}{3}}{\binom{10}{3}}~$ computation is that this alternative computation also happens to represent a valid approach to attacking the problem.